# Coloring JSON output in python

Tags: python, json

In python, If I have a JSON object `obj`, then I can

```
print json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

in order to get a pretty printout of the object. Is it possible to prettify the output even further: *add some colors* in particular? Something like the result of [1]

```
cat foo.json | jq '.'
```

[1] `jq` the JSON Swiss Army toolbox: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: What is `jq`? What does it do?

Comment: Maybe [ipython](http://ipython.org/) has something for this, buy i don't know exactly

Comment: @Tichodroma: Added a reference

Comment: @stalk: I want it to be integrated in the script, such that the output to the console will be colored.

Comment: It is definitely possible (you can just call this `jq` as a subprocess from Python) but if you are asking: "is there a way to do that with the built-in json library" then the answer is "no".

Comment: @freakish: I could live with calling `jq`. Can you explain how can I do it?

Comment: @Dror Actually I was wrong. You can't do this with subprocess, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299550/preserve-colored-output-from-python-os-popen

Comment: @Dror I think that what you are left with is to either search for a library that supports this or write it on your own.

Answer (score 62):

You can use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to color your JSON output. Based on what you have:

```
formatted_json = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

from pygments import highlight, lexers, formatters
colorful_json = highlight(unicode(formatted_json, 'UTF-8'), lexers.JsonLexer(), formatters.TerminalFormatter())
print(colorful_json)
```

Output example:

[image: Output example of pygments colored code]

Comment: What do I need in order to avoid `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined`?

Comment: Then you are using python 3 and should simply use `colorful_json = highlight(formatted_json, lexers.JsonLexer(), formatters.TerminalFormatter())`

Comment: How can I achieve this on Windows?

Comment: `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined` ---> `import unicode`

Answer (score 9):

I like using [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) which has a dependency on pyments. But it covers all your console coloring needs, used in pip to show progress and also autoformats json:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to be working with more recent versions of Pygments and Python. So here's how you can do it in Pygments 2.7.2+:

```
import json
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters.terminal256 import Terminal256Formatter
from pygments.lexers.web import JsonLexer

d = {"test": [1, 2, 3, 4], "hello": "world"}

# Generate JSON
raw_json = json.dumps(d, indent=4)

# Colorize it
colorful = highlight(
    raw_json,
    lexer=JsonLexer(),
    formatter=Terminal256Formatter(),
)

# Print to console
print(colorful)
```

Answer (score 1):

For python3 :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
#coding: utf-8

from pygments import highlight, lexers, formatters
import json

d = {"test": [1, 2, 3, 4], "hello": "world"}

formatted_json = json.dumps(d, indent=4)
colorful_json = highlight(formatted_json, lexers.JsonLexer(), formatters.TerminalFormatter())
print(colorful_json)
```